# Laravel 6 - auth()->user()||Auth::user() not working on a route where verifycsrfToken middleware is disabled, return empty object

Tags: php, laravel

I have two methods in the same controller. Now, one of the routes handles the POST requests from an API and I had to disable the `VerifyCsrfToken middleware` because it wasn't receiving data then, and since it is a callback URL, it has to receive data in order to save or do something to the data. Before I disabled the `VerifyCsrfToken middleware` on the route, the POST request was throwing an error that the page expired. This worked when I disabled the middleware though. Now this developed yet another problem, I can't access the current logged in user through `auth()->user()||Auth::user();`, it returns an empty object yet I can access the logged-in user from the other methods on the same controller. Whoever knows any solution to this problem?

Comment: try after `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work @sta

Comment: make sure u have apply `auth` middleware to that route then only `auth` will work

Comment: so an outside server is sending a POST request to your application? how would this relate to a user's session which is controlled by the cookie in their web browser? or another way: how could this server send a POST request that would authenticate that request to a User on your site?

Comment: @KamleshPaul that route is a callback URL to an API that sends data through POST method.

Comment: @SimonAngatia it doesn't matter  if u want to access `auth()` then u must have to apply `auth` middleware otherwise laravel don't know who is logged in

Comment: @lagbox I need to access the authenticated user for forming the data to send back to the API, to authorize the user to do some transactions

Comment: again, what is this API server sending to your server in this request that would allow this request to be authenticated?

Comment: @lagbox ``` public function bill(Request $request)
     {
        $jsonText = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $json = json_decode($jsonText, true);
        
        // If the request body is empty
        if (empty($json)) {
            return $this->returnAnswer(self::REPLY_SESSION_FAIL);
        }  //do something with the data, then send back the current user balance ```

Comment: do you know how sessions and cookies work and how the default auth setup uses the session for authentication?  these are important to know at this point

Comment: @lagbox it receives JSON data and checks if the user has enough balance then returns JSON object like: `{"OK", $user->balance, "currency"}`

Comment: @lagbox if you have information on the cookies that I am omitting and that can help me solve the problem I will appreciate

Comment: there are more than enough resources on the internet to learn how browsers and cookies work and how cookies and sessions are related ... good luck

Comment: @lagbox I asked in regard to this question, now why tag down my question, I have done a lot of searching on the net. So if you don't know or don't want to help, you don't have to tag down a question!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you will not be able to get an authenticated user from `Auth::user()` because there isn't one for this request.

The only way you would be able to find any User from this request would be if there was some identifying information in the POST request from the other server that you could then use to match to a User yourself.

To make this even simpler:

If you log into your website, then I (from a completely different host and client) send a request to your server am I now authenticated as you? NO

This is the same exact thing happening here.

**Also:**

This route shouldn't have the `web` group of middleware assigned to it since it is not using sessions. This group is what does the CSRF token check as well (which is session based). Might be better in `api.php` but would require updating the other server with a different URL unless you change the prefix for the API routes.